# Haskell Length function implementation

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell programming, and I am trying to understand how lists work, hence I attempted writing two possible `length` functions:

```
myLength :: [a] -> Integer
myLength  = foldr (\x -> (+) 1) 0

myLength1 :: [a] -> Integer
myLength1 []     = 0
myLength1 (x:xs) = (+1) (myLength1 xs)
```

Which one is better?

From my point of view, `myLength1` is much easier to understand, and looks natural for operating on lists.

On the other hand, `myLength` is shorter and it does not use recursion; does this imply `myLength` runs faster than  `myLength1`?

Comment: "*myLength1 is much more better to understand, and looks natural*" - I would have said just that about `myLength` :-)

Comment: `foldr` uses recursion as well, it's just an extra abstraction layer. They'll run at mostly the same speed.

Comment: I like `sum . map (const 1)`. Is that weird?

Comment: @Zeta, that weird for me, can you explain it why it calculate list length?

Comment: It was a joke, but: `sum` sums all elements in the list, `map (const 1)` maps every element in the list to `1`. So if you had `map (const 1) ["Hello", "World"]`, you had `[1, 1]` afterwards, and if you `sum` that, you get `2`.

Comment: @Zeta @anru, `foldr (+1) 0` `==` `sum . map (const 1)`, cool stuff :D

Comment: @DanielSanchez nope. `foldr (const (+1)) 0 == foldr (\_ acc -> acc + 1) 0 == sum . map (const 1)`. You have to discard the value of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take in mind this "pseudo implementation" of `foldr`:

```
foldr :: function -> initializer -> [a] -> b
foldr _ i [] = i
foldr f i (x:xs) = x `f` (foldr f i xs)
```

Now we have your code

```
myLength :: [a] -> Integer
myLength  = foldr (\x -> (+) 1) 0

myLength1 :: [a] -> Integer
myLength1 []     = 0
myLength1 (x:xs) = (+1) (myLength1 xs)
```

Since `foldr` is also recursive itself, your myLength1 and myLength will be almost the same but in the first case the recursive call is done by foldr instead of explicitly by yourself. They should run around the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Both functions do the same thing : foldr use recursion and will end up executing similarly to your directly recursive function. It could be argued that the foldr version is cleaner (once you're accustomed to them, higher order function are often more readable than direct recursion).

But those two functions are pretty bad : they'll both end up building a big thunk (an unevaluated value) `1 + (1 + (1 + ... + 0)..))` which will take a lot of memory ( O(n) space ) and will slow evaluation. To avoid that you should start adding the 1s from the beginning of the list, like so :

```
betterLength xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go n [] = n
    go n (_:xs) = n `seq` go (n+1) xs
```

The `seq` ensures that n is evaluated before the go function is called recursively and thus there is no accumulation of `+1`. With the `BangPatterns` extension, you can write this :

```
betterLength xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go n [] = n
    go !n (_:xs) = go (n+1) xs
```

It is also possible to do this version with a fold :

```
betterLength = foldl' (\n _ -> n + 1) 0
```

where the `foldl'` start from the **l**eft and is strict (**'**).

Answer (score 0):

Using `foldr`, it can be implemented as:

```
length' xs = foldr (\_ n -> 1 + n) 0 xs
```

Explanation:

The lambda function `(\_ x -> n + 1)` will increment the accumulator by one every time there is an element. For instance:

```
lenght' [1..4]
```

will be applied as:
    `1 + ( 1 + ( 1 + ( 1 + 0)))`

Recall that `foldr` is defined like this:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f v [] = v
foldr f v (x:xs) = f x (foldr f v xs)
```